# Pointer to the element of two dimensional array. How can I pass it to the function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I created two dimensional array of char. Size is specified by user.

```
N = atoi(argv[1]);
char table[N][N];
// fill it
```

Now I need a function, which has a pointer to any element of this array. I want to use recurency to walk through this matrix (in both dimensions). Is it possible to define such a function? How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will take your table as an argument: `process_table(table, N, N)`

```
void process_table(char *input_table, unsigned int x_dimension, unsigned int y_dimension)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Then, if you need to iterate over the values in your matrix:

```
void process_table(char *input_table, unsigned int x_dimension, unsigned int y_dimension)
{
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
      // operate on the array element *(input_table + i + y*j)
    }
}
```

Comment: prir01.c: In function ‘main’:
prir01.c:91:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘check_table’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
prir01.c:51:8: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[(long unsigned int)(N)]’

Are these warnings all right?

Comment: @ObscureRobot You need to either cast input_table to a char array of the right sizes, or you have to do the row/column arithmetic yourself.

Comment: @ciembor It would help if you told us what the offending line of code is.

Comment: line 51: `bool check_table(char **table, unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {`
line 91 `check_table(table, 0, 0);`

Comment: @ciembor You can solve the problem by casting table to (char **), but that doesn't solve your real problem because how are you going to cast it back to a multi-dimensional array.  I don't believe you can do that to a variable-based array length (i.e. known only at run-time).  Your best bet is to do the row/column addressing yourself.

Comment: yeah, I'm writing some test code and you have to take the array in as a pointer. This works if you've got a stack-allocated "2D" array as the OP does. It won't work if you have a dynamically allocated array-of-arrays.

Comment: `void check_table(char **table, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int N) {` ... `printf("%c", *( (char *)table + N*i + j)  );`

This works:).

Answer (score 2):

The answer by ObscureRobot is okay, and there is also another solution below.

Use `typedef` and let the compiler manage the offset of the array. See the code below.

```
#include <assert.h>

void test(char **table, int y) /* the x dimension is not needed here */
{
    typedef char array_t[y];
    typedef array_t *array_ptr;
    array_t *tmp_array = (array_ptr)table;
    /* and access the table */
    tmp_array[1][2] = 1;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char table[2][3];
    table[1][2] = 0;
    assert(table[1][2] == 0);
    test((char**)table, 3);
    assert(table[1][2] == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Edited: Sorry but I uploaded an incorrect version at first, which is corrected now. If you can't get it compiled, use the current code or check if there is an additional asteroid like it in `array_t *tmp_array = (*array_ptr)table;`, line 7. If so, just remove the latter one.

Also, the code works fine on my laptop with `gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease)`
 with compiling options `gcc a.c` or `gcc a.c -ansi`